# Can't resolve 'child_process'

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my main.ts file:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const fs = require('fs');
import * as child from 'child_process';

const components = fs.readdirSync(`src/app`);
components.forEach(component => compileComponent(component));

 function compileComponent(component) {    
    const buildJsFiles = `ng run elements:build --aot --main='MyProject/my-components/src/app/${component}/compile.ts'`;
    const bundleIntoSingleFile = `cat dist/tmp/runtime.js dist/tmp/main.js > dist/tmp/my-${component}.js`;
    const copyBundledComponent = `cp dist/tmp/my-${component}.js dist/components/`;
    child.execSync(`${buildJsFiles} && ${bundleIntoSingleFile} && ${copyBundledComponent}`);
 }
```

However, I get the error: Can't resolve 'child_process'.

In my webpack.config.js file I have:

```
externals: { child_process: 'child_process' },
```

I don't use Electron. I also tried adding in package.json:

```
"browser":{ "child_process": false }
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Angular code is compiled targeting browser clients, and you cannot use `child_process` on a browser. So I assume that webpack does not bundle that library, hence why the error.

Adding `"browser":{ "moduleName": false }` instructs the bundling tool to not bundle the module for the build.  This is useful for instance for `crypto` module, for which you've got a browser API that you'd want to use instead of the node js module. But this will not fork for `child_process`, for which there is no browser API.